# Build fat binary for INTEL and M1 on M1 mac

Tags: swift, compilation, project, apple-silicon

I have a XCode project developed for long time. Now I have an M1 Mac too and want to create a fat binary.

If I compile the project (XCode 12.3) on the M1, an INTEL based Mac can not execute it, because it needs OS 11! (it has 10.15.7). These are the settings:

[image]

Using the same project on the INTEL based Mac and compile there, it (also XCode 12.3) delivers an app which runs on the INTEL mac.
Where is the wrong setting?